# Algebraic vs. logarithmic and transcendental branch points

Tags: complex-analysis

I understand that if you take the function $z\mapsto z^{1/x}$ for integer $x$, there is an *algebraic* branch point at the origin for positive integer $x$. My question is what happens if $x$ is positive but irrational?

Does the  branch point become transcendental?  Or does it become logarithmic? Or does it remain algebraic?

My intuition:  If we look at monodromy, there should be infinite branches because the irrationality of $x$ makes it impossible to cycle back to the first branch (or any branch). So my guess is that it becomes a logarithmic branch point. Note that $z^{1/x}=e^{ (\log z)/x} $.   If $x$ is integer, then the branches are finite, but otherwise my guess is that there is a logarithmic branch point.